# Find values such that the integral is convergent

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

Fix $a>0$, and find the values $s\in \mathbb{R}$ such that the following integral is convergent:

$$I:= \int_4^{+\infty} \dfrac{1}{7+a^{sx} \sqrt{x}}\, dx$$

My attempt: I tried to compare $f(x):=\dfrac{1}{7+a^{sx} \sqrt{x}}$ with a function of the form $g(x):=\dfrac{1}{x^p}$, evaluating the limit of $\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ and then applying the limit comparison test.  But I got nowhere, since $f(x)$ has a term of the form $a^{sx}$.

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear... Which integral do you actually want to work on?

Comment: @abiessu I edited the text. I want to solve the original question, hopefully it is clear now.

Comment: If $a>0$ is fixed, you should see the cases: $s>0,s=0$ and $s<0$. The easy case is when $s=0$ because we have $\int_{4}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{7+\sqrt{x}}dx$ which doesn't converges. When $s>0$ you should see first in $0<s<1$- and then in $s>1$. The similar way for $s<0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for user1027216, I guess that now it works.

If $0<a<1, \, s<0$, we can find an $k<0$ (namely, $k=2s|\log(a)|$) such that $$\lim_{x\to\infty} (f(x)/\exp(kx)) = 0$$ Then $f(x) <\exp(kx)$ for $x$ sufficiently large, so there is an $N\in\mathbb{R}$ such that  $$\int_N^\infty f(x) \, dx \leq \int_N^\infty \exp(kx)\, dx<\infty $$ So $ \int_4^\infty f(x)\, dx$ converges.

If $a<0<1$, $s>0$, then $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = \dfrac{1}{7} \neq 0$ which implies that the integral diverges.

If $a=1$ or $s=0$, then $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{7+\sqrt{x}} $ and his improper integral diverges, since $\int_4^\infty \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}}  \, dx$ diverges (Apply the limit comparison test).

The remaining cases are without loss of generality. If $a>1, s<0$, then $$f(x)= \dfrac{1}{7+\left(\dfrac{1}{a}\right)^{-sx}\sqrt{x}}$$And $0<1/a<1$, $-s>0$ so the integral converges. In the same way, $a>1, s>0$ implies that the integral diverges.